# 'this' in function.call() behaves differently when this is not present

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript
Why the function.call() behaves differently with `this` and without `this`.

The program with `this` in `test.call()` and result is same when `this` is replaced by `undefined`

```js
function test(a,b){
    console.log(a+b);
}

let args = [1,2]
test.call(this,...args);

// Output: 3
```

The program without `this` in `test.call()`

```js
function test(a,b){
    console.log(a+b);
}

let args = [1,2]
test.call(...args);

// Output: NaN
```

Comment: I think this link will help you to understand in more detail.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: .call needs a reference as first argument

Comment: "*and result is same when this is replaced by `undefined`*" but `test.call(...args);` is **not** replacing `this` with `undefined`. That invocation is equivalent to `test.call(1, 2);` so, `this = 1`, `a = 2`, and `b = undefined`.

Comment: the `this` parameter is not optional, if you want it to be `undefined` then call `call` like so: `test.call(undefined, ...args)`, otherwise `args[0]` (in this case `1`) will be used as `this`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @Durga this is not a duplicate. The other SO question may help clarify a little bit but it's in no way a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you pass args into the `this` in test function not into (a, b).
You can add `console.log(this)` to checkout the different between two cases.

```js
function test(a,b){
    console.log(this) // number 1
    console.log(a) // number 2
    console.log(b) // undefined
    console.log(a+b) // 2 + undefined will be NaN
}

let args = [1,2]
test.call(...args);
```

So, that means the first argument will be `this`.
If you pass the string in first argument, your this will be "hihihi"

```js
function test(a,b){
    console.log(this) // "hihihi"
    console.log(a) // number 1
    console.log(b) // number 2
}

let args = [1,2]
test.call("hihihi", ...args);
```

Answer (score 1):

call function require the first parameter as 'this' object, if you do not need it, just pass null.

```
test.call(null, ...args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is to use `.call()` with this as the first argument. You can read more about [Function.prototype.call here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
func.call(this, arg1, arg2, ...argN)
```

or you can omit it by passing null:

```
func.call(null, arg1, arg2, ...argN)
```